# Get all comments from disqus rss feed

Tags: rss, disqus, web-crawler

How do I paginate through this rss feed to view all comments?
http://npr2way.disqus.com/dead_mice_are_going_to_be_dropped_on_guam_from_helicopters_really/latest.rss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use our API to get more results than what the RSS feed shows. This endpoint will get comments in a thread, up to 100: http://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/listPosts/ (rss, json or jsonp format)

If this is for a development project, you can also use our cursor method to paginate through all the results, which is documented here: http://disqus.com/api/docs/cursors/