# How to expand all comments on CNN articles?

Tags: javascript, ajax, scripting, html-parsing

This problem can be addressed to all CNN articles,

In example:

http://edition.cnn.com/2013/08/08/health/gupta-changed-mind-marijuana/index.html

I'd like to show, open or expand all the comments, instead of clicking 'Load more comments' which takes forever.

For example for Reddit, [there is a plugin for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reddit-all-comments-viewe/djifpbcmaphjihhelcdeannijfelfnbh?hl=en).

But I'm looking for jQuery/JS code to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First (change  the focus of your console to the comments iframe)

Example: URL =

```
http://disqus.com/embed/comments/?f=cnn&t_i=%2F2013%2F08%2F08%2Fhealth%2Fgupta-changed-mind-marijuana%2Findex.html&t_u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnn.com%2F2013%2F08%2F08%2Fhealth%2Fgupta-changed-mind-marijuana%2Findex.html&t_e=Why%20I%20changed%20my%20mind%20on%20weed&t_d=Dr.%20Sanjay%20Gupta%3A%20Why%20I%20changed%20my%20mind%20on%20weed%20-%20CNN.com&t_t=Why%20I%20changed%20my%20mind%20on%20weed&t_c=207582&s_o=default&disqus_version=1375990054#1
```

Once you are in the comments page / iframe focus execute the following javascript in your chrome console:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
     if (!$('div.load-more a').hasClass('busy')) { 
           $('div.load-more a').click() 
     } 
},1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know precisely what you are aiming to by expanding all comments but you might want to check this post:

[Get all comments from disqus rss feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043761/get-all-comments-from-disqus-rss-feed)